# Unable to overwrite a hidden file in Java. When I attempt to with my code I get java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)

Tags: java, file, java-io

```
  private static boolean replaceUserPassword(String lineToBeReplaced, String replacementLine) {     
   try
    {
    File file = new File(defaultPath);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -H " + file.getCanonicalPath());
    System.out.println(file.isHidden());

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = "", oldtext = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
        oldtext += line + "\r\n";
        }
    reader.close();

    //To replaces line in defaultPath file
    String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(lineToBeReplaced, replacementLine);

    file.setWritable(true);
    if(file.canWrite()){
        System.out.println("writing");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(defaultPath, false);
        writer.write(newtext);
        writer.close();
    }

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H " + file.getCanonicalPath());

  }
catch (IOException ioe)
  {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    return false;
  }
    return true;
```

}

I don't have the file open in any other windows, and the process works when I unhide the file in the original folder.
Thank you for any future assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get canonical path of a hidden file unless until it is set unhide. And hence is the error thrown.

Change :

```
File file = new File(defaultPath);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -H " + file.getCanonicalPath());
System.out.println(file.isHidden());
```

To :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "attrib -H " + defaultCanonicalPath );
// OR
// Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "attrib -H " + defaultPath );
File file = new File( defaultPath );
System.out.println( file.isHidden() );
```

And, it should be working.

Comment: Hey I changed my code up you have shown and now it unhides the file.  However it still shows the same error when trying to overwrite the file. Any ideas why? Also, the System.out.println(file.isHidden) still returns true though when running through the code initially, but if run again it returns false.